# htaccess url having slashes not matched

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following configuration in .htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /coaster/CoasterInsider/
RewriteRule searchResults/keyword/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=searchResults&keyword=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule searchResults/keyword/(.*)/start/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=searchResults&keyword=$1&start=$2 [L,NC]
```

But `start=$2` is not matching. example:
url is: `localhost/coaster/CoasterInsider/searchResults/keyword/a/start/3/`
But when I try to `echo $_GET['keyword']` that's printing `a/start/3/` and start is not getting any value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to invert the order of the last two rules.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, The rule is matching the first one rule and next rules are not being matched :) Thanks